# Динамическое создание listitem

Tags: android, java

Динамически создаю ListItem'ы:

```
public static ListItem[] listItem; 
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
            listItem = new ListItem(context, array.get(i).toString());
            listItem.setId(i);
            layout.addView(listItem);
}
```

Но это просто динамическое создание, с ними нельзя работать, т.е обращаться по айди или еще как нибудь. При клике на определенный итем мне нужно делать определенные действия. Допустим:

```
if (listItem.getId() == 0)
{
    // делаем что либо
}
```

Можно указать айди у одного компонента, и обращаться к нему, но если у меня их нное количество? Если создать массив листитемов и дать им айди, то при клике нужно будет указывать что-то вроде: `istItems[id].getId()` Но как мне узнать айди при клике? Как это реализовать? Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, Вам просто нужно почитать, как это нужно делать. Начните с этой статьи - [Урок 42. Список - ListView](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview.html) и дальше по списку. В районе [51 урока](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/110-urok-51-simpleadapter-dobavlenie-i-udalenie-zapisej.html) самое оно:)